# Powershell: Pass parameter by name toa com object function

Tags: powershell, com

How can I pass parameters to a com-object function by name rather than by position?

Specifically, I've a com-object function ([Word document com-object SaveAs2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084.aspx)) and for example I want to pass values to the 2 first parameters and to the last parameter (CompatibilityMode).

Comment: Don't think it can be done. You can shortcut it somewhat though: `$Arglist = "Document.docx",16 + (,$null*14) + 12`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Neat idea, but I'm still hopeful. I've sent this to "The Scripting Guys" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer on Stackoverflow (short answer - you cannot directly):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544844/how-to-call-a-complex-com-method-from-powershell